# Using vector of pairs with user-defined class objects

Tags: c++, class, vector, user-defined-types, std-pair

I'm trying to write a board game playing program (in C++). I have 2 classes called `Move` and `Board`. In my `Board` constructor, I am using a `pair<char, Move>`. It seems like it is not recognizing the class `Move`, even though I `#include` it in the header file. I get the error message: "missing ',' before identifier 'coord' " and " 'coord' : undeclared identifier". Here is my code:

Move.h:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Move{
    private:
        pair<int,int> coordinates;
    public:
        Move(int,int);
};
```

Move.cpp:

```
#include "Move.h"

Move::Move(int x, int y){
    coordinates.first = x;
    coordinates.second = y;
}
```

Board.h:

```
#include "Move.h"

class Board{
    private:
        vector<pair<char, Move> > board_state;
    public:
        Board(vector<pair<char, Move> >);
};
```

Board.cpp:

```
#include "Board.h"

Board::Board(vector<pair<char P, Move coord> > state){
     board_state = state;
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do with those identifiers `P` and `coord` in the constructor parameter `vector<pair<char P, Move coord> > state`?

Comment: Mind including your main function?

Comment: 1) Do not place `using namespace std;` in header files.  2) Your `include` files are missing include guards.

Comment: In addition, why are you including `<vector>` in your `Move` header?  There is no usage of `vector` there.

Comment: With respect to general style, it may be a useful exercise for you to post your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template arguments for `pair` should be types only. So `vector<pair<char P, Move coord>>` should read `vector<pair<char, Move>>`.